# R gsub insert into large string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to insert substring `"A"` into a string of length > 65536 at position `n`. I am using gsub to do this since it is very efficient.

```
n = 5
text <- paste(rep("a", 70000), collapse = "")
lhs <- '^(.{n})(.*)$'
rhs <- '\\1A\\2'
gsub(lhs, rhs, text, perl=TRUE)
```

When I choose n to be small, e.g. 5, the code works fine. If however `n = 66000` the following error message shows:

```
In gsub(lhs, rhs, text, perl = TRUE) : PCRE pattern compilation error
    'number too big in {} quantifier'
    at '})(.*)$'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems PCRE has some limitation enforced for the max argument in limiting quantifiers. It is still impressive since TRE has a limit of just 256 chars in the same contruct. Did you try with `stringr::str_replace`? It may be more reliable in this case.

Comment: Another idea is to split the construct into parts: `gsub('^(.{n/2})(.{n/2})(.*)$', '\\1\\2A\\3', text, perl=TRUE)` (pseudo, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you won't be able to use `sub` here due to pattern length restrictions.  But actually, for this problem the base string functions should work and probably would be more efficient anyway:

```r
insertA <- function(x, n) {
    return(paste0(substring(x, 1, n-1), "A", substring(x, n, nchar(x))))
}

text <- paste(rep("a", 30), collapse = "")
insertA(text, 5)

[1] "aaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

This approach simply uses `substring` along with `paste` to split the `A` character in between whatever two halves the user chooses.